# Embed Web Page in Livecode

Tags: android, ios, livecode

I just started using [Livecode](http://livecode.com/) which seems to be really easy to work. I wished to know i there is any way as how I would be able to embed a webpage(live webpage such as google.com) on to the app. So when I create the app(standalone app), the user would actually be working with a web app. I see this would be an easy way to convert a web app into a mobile app(iOs and Android).

Edit : Till now this is what I am doing :

1. Create a new mainstack.
2. Click on code(on the top menu), that takes me to the stack code. It is where I am pasting the code below that [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807423/mark) has mentioned.

Not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you just copied the script and pasted it into a script editor without thinking. Please, read chapter 5 of the User Manual (see LiveCode's Help menu) or read chapter 2 of my book.

Answer (score 0):

This code creates a browser.

```
mobileControlCreate "browser"
put the result into gBrowserID
mobileControlSet gBrowserID,"url","http://www.google.com"
mobileControlSet gBrowserID,"visible",true
mobileControlSet gBrowserID,"rect,the rect of this cd
```

Make sure to read the entries about these commands in the dictionary. I didn't include error checking. You need to declare gBrowserID as a global variable. That will allow you to delete the browser control when you open a different card or stack.

---

It seems you are thinking that above code would just run. It won't, because it needs to be placed inside a handler. A possibility is a mouseUp handler:

```
on mouseUp
  // script goes here
end mouseUp
```

Comment: Should I add these in the stack script or the card script? Sorry, I'm really new to this.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Which action do you want to trigger the script?

Comment: I want the website to be displayed on the app's entire screen. Its just like converting a website into an app.

Comment: That's what it does. Try it.

Comment: No working for me. Can you please point me to any tutorial for this.

Comment: The purpose of SO is to provide full answers instead of linking to tutorials. Please, adjust your question to include the code that you have so far. That will allow me to see where you're getting stuck. You didn't answer my question: which event should display the website?

Comment: Made an edit in the question, added a few details. Should you need more details let me know.

Comment: I have added a little info. You really need to read Ch. 5 of the User Manual or Ch. 2 of my book before asking more questions on SO.